# iframes in IE 10 in Joomla

Tags: iframe, joomla, internet-explorer-10

My users need to be able to use IE 10 to edit inside joomla, but many of the editing features require iframes which aren't working for me in IE10. I personally can use IE and chrome for which it responds perfectly. I have checked the other SO pages on this issue, but this problem isn't solved - in my case the iframes themselves appear, but the content does not.

```
<a rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: (window.getSize().x*80/100), y: (window.getSize().y-50)}}" onclick="IeCursorFix(); return false;" href="http://intranet/joomla/index.php?option=com_dropfiles&amp;tmpl=component&amp;622bd2e85bef868730f677541c3792fa=1&amp;caninsert=1&amp;e_name=jform_articletext&amp;template=system&amp;path=%2Fjoomla" class="modal-button btn" id=""><i class="icon-dropfiles"></i>Files - Dropfiles</a>
```

I have even checked the page which is linked to in ie10, which responds fine. The issue is that the content isn't pulled in correctly.  I am using joomla 3.1.5 and the JCK editor (though these buttons are independent of that).

Comment: does it work in other IE versions such as IE11? Does it also work in other browsers such as FF and Chrome? Also have a look at Joomla's filtering system: http://docs.joomla.org/Help16:Content_Article_Manager#List_Filters

Comment: It works in FF and chrome. I don't have access to IE11. I have looked at the filtering system and don't understand how it could help.

Comment: Why on earth are you using 3.1.5? Update and see if the issue persists, it's not really interesting to spent time solving an issue that may have been addressed already. Also use a powerful editor such as JCE could fix the issue.

Comment: I am going to upgrade. Why is JCE more powerful than JCK?

Comment: Am unable to upgrade. Have posted my query here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080652/upgrading-from-joomla-3-1-5-server-error-500