# How can you fix server error 500, received when upgrading from Joomla 3.1.5?

Tags: joomla, upgrade, joomla3.1

While attempting to upgrade joomla using the button, I receive the server error 500. I have read this joomla forum post which related to my problem, but the update_site table in my server doesn't have any blank entries.

Comment: Check the error logs of your server.

Answer (score 0):

probably your hosting server is weak. So it can not handle this kind of process. 
I suggest:
1) Make a full back-up and restore on localhost, then upgrade to 3.3.4. Make a full back-up and override your old joomla also database.

2) Change hosting company. 
By the way, after check those tips: http://www.joomshaper.com/blog/joomla/how-to-speed-up-joomla-3-3-3-4-and-template